# Mapbox iOS SDK stop updating user position

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, core-location

How to stop updating user position, these to functions no longer exist :

```
mapView.locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
mapView.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

The goal is to use SimulatedLocationManager, to simulate a navigation but the real position keeps updating.

thanks

Comment: `mapView.userTrackingMode: MGLUserTrackingMode` is how you enable and disable the automatic updating of the user's current location in Mapbox.

Comment: My user tracking mode is .followWithCourse. And I need it so the map follows the "simulatedLocationManager"

I need to stop the positions updates of the default location manager